# Add an element to a named list of data.frames in R

Tags: r, list

I am new to R and don't know the correct term for a list of that kind. I would call it a *element named list of data frames*.

```
dfA = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,2,3))
dfB = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,2,3))
mylist = list ('a' = dfA, 'b' = dfB)
```

But now I want to add a new element to it

`dfC = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,2,3))`

I don't know how to do this. I couldn't find examples fitting in my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can assign 'dfC' by either numeric index i.e. 3 or with a `name`

```
mylist[['c']] <- dfC
```

Or use `c` or `append`

```
mylist <- c(mylist, list(c= dfC))
```